# NodeJS - If moving multiple files fails, deleting ones that failed

Tags: node.js, file

I'm trying to upload multiple files with an HTTP post, and then NodeJS handles:

1. save files' info to database
2. move files from tmp folder to permanent folder
3. if any file move fails, delete the file from tmp folder

My two issues are described in the comments within code snippet below:

1. path.resolve isn't working
2. iterator isn't working within fs.rename

```
for (i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    
    const file = new fileSchema({
        _userId: req.body._userId,
        _companyId: req.body._companyId,
        _meetingId: response._id,
        originalFilename: req.files[i].originalname,
        savedFilename: req.files[i].filename,
    });

    file.save().then((response) => { }).catch(error => { console.log(error) });

    const currentPath = path.resolve(temp_folder, req.files[i].filename);
    const newPath = upload_folder +"/"+ req.body._userId +"/"+ req.body._companyId +"/"+ response._id +"/"+ req.files[i].filename;
    // 1. why doesn't path.resolve work with the inputs on the line above? I have to concat a string as in line above?
    
    fs.rename(currentPath, newPath, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error moving files");

            try { removeTempFiles(temp_folder, req.files[i]); } // helper function which works written elsewhere
            // 2. req.files[i] is undefined (even though req.files works) so the line above fails - i.e. the iterator isn't captured within rename?
            catch(err) { console.log(err); }

        } else {
            console.log("Successfully moved the file!");
        }
    });
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
for (i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
```

to this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
```

The addition of `let` will create a separate `i` for each iteration of the `for` loop so it will stay valid inside your `fs.rename()` callback.

---

And, `path.join()`, is probably a better choice than `path.resolve()` for combining path segments.

Comment: Yes the sigh was more because I didn’t see that I missed Let and the debugger wasn’t throwing anything useful for me to pick up on it. The join vs resolve didn’t solve the issue so I’m just leaving it as a string concat. That one isn’t even throwing an error so not sure how to debug it. Code just halts execution.

Comment: @glog - Run your code in strict mode and this would have been an error.  All variables should always be declared in the proper scope and strict mode will help you enforce that.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.